# NodeJS Error: Cannot find module '[object Object]'

Tags: node.js

I have this simple NodeJs code

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();


app.disable('x-powered-by');

var handleBars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});

app.engine('handlebars',handleBars.engine);
app.set('view engine',handleBars);

app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('home');
})

app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log('Working boy');
})
```

and two files `main.handlebars and home.handlebars`.But when i run this code it gives me this following error

```
Error: Cannot find module '[object Object]'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at new View (/Users/muradshahmammadli/Desktop/progr/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:79:30)
    at EventEmitter.render (/Users/muradshahmammadli/Desktop/progr/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/muradshahmammadli/Desktop/progr/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
    at /Users/muradshahmammadli/Desktop/progr/NodeJS/express.js:15:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/muradshahmammadli/Desktop/progr/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/muradshahmammadli/Desktop/progr/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

I tried replacing `res.render('home');` with `res.send("works");` and it worked,but i need to include home page,so what can i do?

Comment: `app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts oh thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The express `view engine` environment variable accepts a string, not an object. You define what the string means when you do

```
app.engine('handlebars', handleBars.engine);
```

so, you must change your `view engine` to

```
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```